# Gas limit being reached when deploying

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-limit, truffle-deployment

I currently have a contract which requires around 16M gas to deploy and execute. Trying to deploy using Parity on Kovan net fails due to gas limit being reached. On my private network I just configured the gas limit of the test server to match my needs, however I assume this won't help when it comes to deploying to an actual network since other miners have lower gas limit settings and since we need a consensus contracts like these simply can't be deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, contracts like these can't currently be deployed, although it may become possible to deploy them in future if and when miners raise the gas limit.

16M gas sounds like a very big contract; You may want to consider breaking it up into a number of smaller ones.